# How to modify GitHub API query in order to receive properly results based on created variable?

Tags: github

I use this query in order to receive results for a specific keyword sorted based on the `created_at` variable. In the query it is created.

Here is an example query:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=%22erp%22created:2017-08-14..2021-04-16T23:34:59Z&sort=created&order=asc&per_page=100&page=10
```

However if you check the `created_at` variable in the result you can see that the results are not ordered.

How can I modify my query properly?

Answer (score 0):

Creation date is not a supported `sort` parameter option for the REST API endpoint [Search repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/search/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-repositories).

The documentation includes this information for the parameter:

> `sort` *string*
>
> Sorts the results of your query by number of `stars`, `forks`, or `help-wanted-issues` or how recently the items were `updated`. Default: [best match](https://docs.github.com/rest/search/search#ranking-search-results)
>
> Can be one of: `stars`, `forks`, `help-wanted-issues`, `updated`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548067/how-to-modify-github-api-query-in-order-to-receive-properly-results-based-on-cre/77548426?noredirect=1#comment136734110_77548426) @foc If you have a new question, you are welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).